# Highcharts large data set clustering

Tags: highcharts, bigdata

I have tens of thousands (possibly hundreds of thousands) of points that I need plotted with Highcharts. Is there a way where I can cluster the data on the server, so it will show less than 1000 points, but as you zoom in it will make AJAX calls to the server to get the data for that zoomed region (it would probably run through the same cluster algorithm). How would this interface with the Highcharts API?

Comment: I'm guessing I would have to catch the `selected` event, then pop up a loading screen, then AJAX Call, then remove data and add new data, but how would the zooming work, because this method would not account for that.

Comment: Actually, I think ^that might work. I think it would account for the zooming since the axes would then update. I would just need to show a Reset Zoom button that would show the original data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an improvement for Barbara's answer,

It registers to the setExtremes event,
to know if this is a reset zoom event.
If it is - it gets the entire dataset,
thus allowing reset zoom to work correctly.

It also allows zooming in both x and y.

http://jsfiddle.net/DktpS/8/

```
var isReset = false;

...

            xAxis: {
                events: {
                        afterSetExtremes : afterSetExtremes,
                    setExtremes: function (e) {


                        if (e.max == null || e.min == null) {
                           isReset = true;                            
                        }
                        else
                        {
                         isReset = false;   
                        }
                    }
                },
                minRange: 3600 * 1000 // one hour
            },

            series: [{
                data: data,
                dataGrouping: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});


    /**
     * Load new data depending on the selected min and max
     */
    function afterSetExtremes(e) {

        var url,
        currentExtremes = this.getExtremes(),
            range = e.max - e.min;
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

        var min = 0;
        var max = 1.35e12;
        if(!isReset)
        {
            min = e.min;
            max = e.max;
        }
         chart.showLoading('Loading data from server...');
        $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/from-sql.php?start=' + Math.round(min) +
            '&end=' + Math.round(max) + '&callback=?', function (data) {

            chart.series[0].setData(data);

            chart.hideLoading();


        });

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a highstock demo that does this http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading.
But you can do the same thing with highcharts http://jsfiddle.net/RHkgr/
The important bit is the afterSetExtremes function

```
...
            xAxis : {
                events : {
                    afterSetExtremes : afterSetExtremes
                },
...


/**
 * Load new data depending on the selected min and max
 */
function afterSetExtremes(e) {

    var url,
        currentExtremes = this.getExtremes(),
        range = e.max - e.min;
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.showLoading('Loading data from server...');
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/from-sql.php?start='+ Math.round(e.min) +
            '&end='+ Math.round(e.max) +'&callback=?', function(data) {

        chart.series[0].setData(data);
        chart.hideLoading();
    });

}
```

Comment: On another note, that jsfiddle doesn't work right, try zooming in then reseting. It needs to refetch the original data

Answer (score 0):

In case when you will not have a limit of points, you can increase [turboThreshold](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.turboThreshold) paramter.

Comment: I have tried that, and it is not practical as I have to support IE8 :"(

Comment: You mean that turbothreshold doesn't work in IE8? Could you recreate your example in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: No, IE8 does not handle that many objects well. It will ask you numerous times if you want to kill the script.